# Did the Apollo 7 "mutiny" have consequences for ground crew?

Tags: apollo-program

The [Apollo 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_7) mission was a troubled one due to the crew's illness and resulted in several heated discussions between the flight crew and ground crew. It seems to me that the ground crew was partly to blame for this as well: for example, from what I've read, schedules were tightened (instead of loosened due to the ill flight crew) and test procedures seem to have been problematic as indicated by Schirra's remarks: *"I wish you would find out the idiot’s name who thought up this test. I want to find out, and I want to talk to him personally when I get back down."*

Due to their behavior, none of the three astronauts were nominated for subsequent flights. But I wonder whether there were any consequences for the ground personal as well? Was the way scheduling was planned changed? Was someone moved to a different job or faced other consequences?

Comment: Fwiw - Schirra had already stated that 7 would be his last flight. As for ground crew "consequences" - the ground crew might say "for what?" - ie Glenn Lunney states that the planning was done well in advance - it wasn't like the ground crew just decided to change things at the last minute. - https://www.airspacemag.com/history-of-flight/02_on2018-forgotten-apollo-7-mission-180970365/

Comment: I wrote something in the answer and then deleted it because I didn't feel it was directly relevant - but yeah, everything they did had been extensively simulated and trained preflight.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not, at least, for the leaders of the ground crew.

> Once Apollo 7 cleared the pad, a three-shift mission control team-led
>   by flight directors Glynn Lunney, Eugene Kranz, and Gerald D. Griffin
>   -- in Houston took over.

[source](https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/history/apollo/apollo-7/apollo-7.html)

[Lunney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glynn_Lunney) would go on to be technical director of the Apollo-Soyuz Test Program, head of the Space Shuttle Program, and after retiring from NASA, program manager at United Space Alliance, the shuttle operations contractor.

[Kranz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Kranz#Later_career) would go on to become director of Mission Operations.

[Griffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_D._Griffin) would go on to assume various upper management positions in NASA, finally as director of Johnson Space Center.

Comment: In Gene Kranz's case, I suspect Apollo 13 played a significantly greater role in his career development than Apollo 7.

Comment: Anyone with a [Kerbal](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Gene_Kerman) modeled after them is a success in my book!